# формат JSON или нет?

Tags: json

Это формат JSON или нет?

```js
{
  "stage": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "type": "net",
      "author": "Bill Dewaine",
      "created": "2017-04-17T10:00:00+03:00",
      "tags": [
        "simple",
        "fool"
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "author": "Seal Milf",
      "created": "2017-03-37T10:00:00+03:00",
      "tags": [
        "simple",
        "fool"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: ДА, это формат JSON

Comment: ОК, тогда в каком виде записать, чтобы работал JSON parse?

Comment: Можно здесь убедиться http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Да, для подобных вопросов рекомендую использовать сервисы на подобии [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: JSON parse преобразует СТРОКУ в JSON. Вы ни секунды не тратите на гугл прежде чем что-то спросить?

Comment: Vladimir Gamalian, спасибо за ссылку помогли ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это объект:

```
var obj = {
  "stage": [
    { "id": "1", "type": "net" },
    { "id": "2", "author": "Seal Milf" }
  ]
}
```

Это строка в формате JSON, которую можно распарсить в объект:

```
var jsonString = '{"stage":[{"id":"1","type":"net"},{"id":"2","author":"Seal Milf"}]}';
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```